# Creating a new Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to creat a new Google Calendar on an existing account with an Android App, like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lngooglecalsync/) Windows Application it does. That Application uses the Gdata API but I don't know how to use it.
I tried the [sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) of the newer [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android), but the sample don't work without enabeling the Calendar API. I want that everyone can use it just with entering the login information like the Windows Application above.

It would be even better if I could creat a new syncable Calendar directly on the Phone with the new [Calendar Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

Has anybody an example for me how to create a new Google Calendar from an Android App?

Thanks a lot in advance!